# Issue rendering django for on template with bootstrap

Tags: django, forms, templates

I am trying to render my django forms in the template using bootstrap and I keep getting an error:
    BoundField' object has no attribute 'fields'

This is what I try:

```
{% for field in layer_form %}
    {{ field | as_bootstrap }}
{% endfor %}
```

If I try this:

```
{{ layer_form|as_bootstrap }}
```

then it works. But I need to loop through the form fields and append some if statements in between.

Any idea what's going on here?

The above works with another form but not with this one:

```
lass ResourceBaseForm(TranslationModelForm):
"""Base form for metadata, should be inherited by childres classes of ResourceBase"""

owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    empty_label="Owner",
    label="Owner",
    required=False,
    queryset=Profile.objects.exclude(
        username='AnonymousUser'),
    widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('ProfileAutocomplete'))

_date_widget_options = {
    "icon_attrs": {"class": "fa fa-calendar"},
    "attrs": {"class": "form-control input-sm"},
    "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
    # Options for the datetimepickers are not set here on purpose.
    # They are set in the metadata_form_js.html template because
    # bootstrap-datetimepicker uses jquery for its initialization
    # and we need to ensure it is available before trying to
    # instantiate a new datetimepicker. This could probably be improved.
    "options": False,
    }
date = forms.DateTimeField(
    localize=True,
    widget=DateTimePicker(**_date_widget_options)
)
temporal_extent_start = forms.DateTimeField(
    required=False,
    localize=True,
    widget=DateTimePicker(**_date_widget_options)
)
temporal_extent_end = forms.DateTimeField(
    required=False,
    localize=True,
    widget=DateTimePicker(**_date_widget_options)
)

poc = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    empty_label="Person (fill form)",
    label="Point Of Contact",
    required=False,
    queryset=Profile.objects.exclude(
        username='AnonymousUser'),
    widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('ProfileAutocomplete'))

metadata_author = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    empty_label="Person (fill form)",
    label="Metadata Author",
    required=False,
    queryset=Profile.objects.exclude(
        username='AnonymousUser'),
    widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('ProfileAutocomplete'))

keywords = TaggitField(
    required=False,
    help_text=_("A space or comma-separated list of keywords"),
    widget=TaggitWidget('TagAutocomplete'))

regions = TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField(
    required=False,
    queryset=Region.objects.all(),
    level_indicator=u'___')
regions.widget.attrs = {"size": 20}
```

With this simple form it works:

```
class UploadCSVForm(forms.Form):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UploadCSVForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['selected_country'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=get_country_names(), required=True)

title = forms.CharField(max_length=80, required=True)

LAYER_TYPE = (
    ('1', 'Global Layer'),
    ('2', 'Layer by Region'),
    ('3', 'Layer by Province'),
)
layer_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LAYER_TYPE, required=True)
csv = forms.FileField(required=True)
permissions_json = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

Comment: have you tried {{ layer_form.field_name|as_bootstrap }}?? just check this, if it doesnt works, then it wont work like that with fields, it will work solely with forms only

Comment: @Exprator I tried but I get: 'str' object has no attribute 'fields' So what does it mean? That I can not loop through the fields of the form? I can just render them all together?

Comment: yes, if that error is being shown then the form has to be used as a whole, or else you can use other bootstrap app for django and not this deprecated pinax bootstrap

Comment: Hmm. But what this error means exactly?

Comment: means the bootstrap filter is not being able to work with fields, it need form attribute, if you remove the as_bootstrap from the fields inside for loop you will see the fields are being rendered

Comment: Yes. It works indeed. But what is strange is that I have used this in another template with a different forms.py and it worked. This makes me thing that this is something related with the structure of the form.

Comment: ohh, that is strange, can you post that form and this form so that we can see if the form is having any problem or not

Comment: Sure. I edited the question

Comment: you havent mentioned any model for that form, class Meta:
        model = The model name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150059/discussion-between-user1919-and-exprator).